# Wheel building for n360 + disc brakes on H Plus Son 700c, 36h

Tags: wheels, hub, spokes

I'm working on building a couple of wheels for a road/commuter bike. This is my first wheel building endeavor. I have:

- 2 H Plus Son 700c, 36 hole wheels
- A Nuvinci n360, 2012 model
- A set of TRP Hylex Hydraulic Disc Brakes

I need:

- A front disc hub
- Spokes
- Spoke nipples

Here are my questions:

- What length of spokes will I need? Is there a spoke length calculator out there that actually works?
- Any tips for me at I go through my first wheel build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like the spoke length calculator, [Edd](https://leonard.io/edd/). It has a database of hubs and rims which makes it quite straight forward to use. There are others, a search on "spoke length calculator" will find you lots to choose from.

As far as wheel building advice goes, I highly, highly recommend Jobst Brandt's book [The Bicycle Wheel](http://www.avocet.com/wheelbook/wheelbook.html). I used it to build my first wheel many years ago. The method is clear and easy to follow and there is a wealth of information on wheels and how they work.

You may also find this [answer on wheel building](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-to-build-a-wheel?rq=1) and this [answer on spoke length calculation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-do-i-calculate-spoke-length?lq=1) helpful.

Comment: In addition to this, take your time, and do not give up.  Wheelbuilding takes time to do properly.

Comment: Yes! I tend to think of it as meditation – trying to focus on doing one fairly simple thing over and over with enough attention to get it right.